# Elsarticle, apalike, &, doi

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle, bibliographystyle

Good day! I need to use  \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}  in my article. But I have problems with bibliographystyle:

1. In the reference list I don't see doi.
2. I would need "&" instead of "and" in both reference list and reference style.

Here is my code:

```
 @article{gonzalez'18,
  title   = "Sequences of purchases in credit card data reveal lifestyles in urban populations.",
  journal = "Nat Commun",
  volume  = "9",
  pages   = "118--173",
  year    = "2018",
  doi    = "https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-05690-8",
  author  = "Gonzalez, Marta C. and Di Clemente, Riccardo and Luengo-Oroz, Miguel  and  Travizano, Matias and  Xu, Sharon and   Vaitla, Bapu "}


\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}\biboptions{authoryear,sort,comma}

\begin{document}
...\citep[see][]{cjm-ex'17, gonzalez'18,  cjm'17,  xin'18,  wei, liu'13, vaganov'17}.  
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}

}
```

It doesn't work well with \bibliographystyle{apacite} (because I need eslarticle). It doesn't work well with \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} because year of publication is not in brackets, but I need it like here:
Gonzalez, M. C., Di Clemente, R., Luengo-Oroz, M., Travizano, M., Xu, S., and Vaitla, B. (2018). Sequences of purchases in credit card data reveal lifestyles in urban populations. Nat Commun, 9:118–173.

Is this possible to fix problems 1) and/or 2)?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "It doesn't work well with `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}` because year of publication is not in brackets". For sure, `\citet{gonzalez'18}` produces `Gonzalez et al. (2018)`.

Comment: With  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}  I have this in the reference list: Di Clemente, R., Luengo-Oroz, M., Travizano, M., Xu, S., Vaitla, B., Gonzalez, M.C., 2018. Sequences of purchases in credit card data reveal lifestyles in urban populations. Nat Commun 9, 118–173. doi:https://doi.org/10. 1038/s41467-018-05690-8.

Comment: But I need: Di Clemente, R., Luengo-Oroz, M., Travizano, M., Xu, S., Vaitla, B., Gonzalez, M.C., (2018). Sequences of purchases in credit card data reveal lifestyles in urban populations. Nat Commun 9, 118–173. doi:https://doi.org/10. 1038/s41467-018-05690-8.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking these small details, but it seems that the journal needs this.

Comment: If the journal has very specific formatting requirements, it really should provide a bst file for authors. A separate thought: If the *only* formatting aspect that's not right about the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style is that it fails to place parentheses around the year, you could edit the bbl file by hand and insert the parentheses where needed. Obviously, do this only at the very end, right before you submit the paper to the journal.